# Extracting arguments from received call and assert on them

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

How can I do assertions on arguments from a received call? The below example does not work, because the action passed to `Arg.Do()` is never called.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> receivedlArgs = null;
provider.Received(1)
    .SetValuesAsync(Arg.Do<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>>>(
    args =>
    {
        receivedlArgs = args.Select(a => new Tuple<string, string>(a.Key, a.Value.ToString()));
    }));

// assert (using FluentAssertions - but just for the example)
receivedlArgs.Should().Equal(Tuple.Create("Key1", "foo"), Tuple.Create("Key2", "bar"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard approach is to assert a call with the correct arguments was received, rather than capturing the argument and asserting on it.

```
provider.Received(1)
    .SetValuesAsync(Arg.Is<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>>>(
    pairs => SameElements(pairs, new [] { Tuple.Create("Key1", "foo"), ... })));
```

You can extract more or less of this code into different methods to make it more readable.

The problem with this approach is it doesn't give as much information about the differences between the arguments as something like FluentAssertions. In those cases we can fall back to `When..Do` or `Arg.Do` to capture the argument as per your question. In those cases we don't want to use `Received`, we just stub out the call to perform a particular action whenever it is called. Also make sure you are setting up the `Do` callback before the method being tested is called.

```
//Arrange
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> receivedArgs = null;
provider.SetValuesAsync(
  Arg.Do<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>>>(x => receivedArgs = x)
);
// Act:
callWeAreTesting();
// Assert:
receivedArgs.Should()....
```

Or we can use `When..Do` syntax:

```
provider.WhenForAnyArgs(x => x.SetValuesAsync(null))
        .Do(x => receivedArgs = x.Args<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>>>());
```

Comment: I really wish there would be a more expressive way (both on the assert DSL side and on the failure output side) to combine (best of breed) nsubstitute and fluent assertions,

Comment: Agreed. There has been a bit of work done on this (some basic plumbing exists), but we have never defined the feature well enough to implement and ship: https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/160#issuecomment-53013051